# Color bars in multi subplots doesn't follow the same scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to compare four two dimensional histograms. And i need the color bar in every one of these histograms. But, it's obvious that the color scale in all histograms is not the same. There is a way to make this scale the same?.

[image]

The code i used is down here:

```
plt.set_cmap('hot')


fig = plt.figure()

fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)

# Adds subplot on position 1
ax = fig.add_subplot(221,aspect='equal')
# Adds subplot on position 2
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, aspect='equal')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223, aspect='equal')

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, aspect='equal')


h = ax.hist2d(data,datay,bins=(100,100), rasterized=True,range=np.array([(-7.9, 7.9), (-7.9, 7.9)]))


ax.set_title('step size = 2.0 ', size= 16, fontname='Comic Sans MS')


h2 = ax2.hist2d(data2,datay2,bins=(100,100), rasterized=True,range=np.array([(-7.9, 7.9), (-7.9, 7.9)]))
ax2.set_title('step size = 5.0 ', size= 16, fontname='Comic Sans MS')



h3 = ax3.hist2d(data3,datay3,bins=(100,100), rasterized=True,range=np.array([(-7.9, 7.9), (-7.9, 7.9)]))
ax3.set_title('step size = 6.0 ', size= 16, fontname='Comic Sans MS')
    

h4 = ax4.hist2d(data4,datay4,bins=(100,100), rasterized=True,range=np.array([(-7.9, 7.9), (-7.9, 7.9)]))
ax4.set_title('step size = 8.0 ', size= 16, fontname='Comic Sans MS')


"""
DEFINING COLOR BARS
"""
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(h[3], cax=cax)


divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(h2[3], cax=cax)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax3)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(h3[3], cax=cax)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax4)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(h4[3], cax=cax)

ax2.set_yticks([])
ax4.set_yticks([])

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)


plt.savefig('24pog.pdf') 
plt.savefig('24pog.png') 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The problem with `plt.hist2d` is, to apply the same "color scaling" to your four data instances, you must know in advance the binned values of the four histograms but you don't know those values until you have plotted the histograms.

A possible solution is just to plot twice the histograms, the second time you will know the full range of binned data, but it seems wasteful.

Another approach, you plot the four histograms, read the binned data range and then you change the attributes of the color meshes that `hist2d`'s have returned, but it seems complicated.

In my opinion, the simplest, most economical approach is to mimic `hist2d` on our own, here you can see its source code (nb: `self` is an Axes instance)

```
def hist2d(self, x, y, bins=10, range=None, density=False, weights=None,
           cmin=None, cmax=None, **kwargs):
    ...
    h, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins, range=range,
                                       density=density, weights=weights)
    ...
    pc = self.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, h.T, **kwargs)
    self.set_xlim(xedges[0], xedges[-1])
    self.set_ylim(yedges[0], yedges[-1])

    return h, xedges, yedges, pc
```

Well, nothing extraordinarily fancy… so the plan is to call `histogram2d` on every `x, y` instance, save the results in a list, inspect the binned data to find the proper normalization and finally, using the data we saved from `histogram2d`, call `pcolormesh` — note that you can also use the same axis limits for all the plots, if you want.

Here is the code that I've used

```
In [49]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
    ...: from numpy.random import rand
    ...: from numpy import histogram2d
    ...: 
    ...: # generate data - I have not your data…
    ...: data = ((rand(10000+500*i), rand(10000+500*i)) for i in range(4))
    ...: 
    ...: # generate histograms (for you it's for x, y in ((x1,x2),(x2,y2),...)
    ...: hist = [histogram2d(x,y) for x, y in data]
    ...: # find min and max for each histogram
    ...: min_, max_ = zip(*((h.min(), h.max()) for h, xedges, yedges in hist))
    ...: 
    ...: norm = plt.Normalize(min(min_), max(max_))
    ...: sm = ScalarMappable(norm, 'hot')
    ...: 
    ...: fig, sp = plt.subplots(2, 2, constrained_layout=1)
    ...: sp = sp.flatten()
    ...: for ax, (h, xedges, yedges) in zip(sp, hist):
    ...:     ax.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, h.T, norm=norm, cmap='hot')
    ...: plt.colorbar(sm, ax=sp, aspect=30)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to normalize the color range (look at `cmax`, `cmin` in the docs. Alternatively, you can use a `ScalarMappable`, i.e.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np

norm = plt.cm.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = 2)
cmap = 'hot'
sc = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap =  cmap)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for idx, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axi.hist2d(*np.random.rand(2, 10), cmap = cmap)
    fig.colorbar(sc, ax = axi)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do i get vmax? There is a way to obtain this from the histograms? Or i need to put it by hand?

Comment: @Daumann yep, assuming you want to automate `vmin` and `vmax`, you'd just extract them with `min()` and `max()` (otherwise manual values will still work)

Comment: @Daumann if you want colorbars to reflect the same range you have to tell matplotlib on what that range is from your data. Alternatively you can normalize everything with the `Normalize` class but that looses the "absolute" scale.

Comment: As a side note; if all colorbars are in the same range, one can also just put 1 colorbar in with `fig.colorbar(sc, ax = ax)` given that ax is the 2d matrix above).